# Les snow days au Canada

Tags: vocabulaire, canada

Le lycée dans lequel je travaille vient d'annoncer qu'il n'y a pas d'école aujourd'hui : c'est un snow day.

En cherchant [ce mot sur WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/snow%20day), je trouve « école fermée pour cause de neige », ainsi que cette constatation assez raisonnée :

> Étant donné qu'il neige rarement assez en France pour que les écoles soient régulièrement fermées, pas d'expression toute faite en français.

Il est néanmoins des pays comme le mien où on parle français *et* on doit fermer les écoles pour cause de neige.

Sur [le site web du conseil scolaire Viamonde](https://csviamonde.ca/) ici à Toronto, je trouve cette alerte :

> 28 FÉV. 2020 · En raison des conditions météorologiques, les écoles suivantes sont fermées. ...

D'autres recherches, telle que [celle-ci sur Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%22snow%20day%22), n'ajoutent que du charabia, ou même rien.

Je me serais étonné de devoir croire qu'on ne parle de ce phénomène tellement essentiel, tellement formateur, à la vie de tout enfant au Canada que par de lourdes locutions.

Y a-t-il une autre manière ?

Comment: « Conditions météorologiques » est le terme générique pour toute fermeture d’établissement public pour cause d’intempéries : neige, verglas, inondation, tempête …

Comment: Seeing the "snow day" and the "strike day?" announced on the same web page makes me wonder if there's an "expression toute faite" in France/français for when Students get a day off because their teachers are striking (NOT the Students themselves) and if not, whether *WordReference* would blame the lack of a fixed term on there not being enough strikes in France to justify it? (All that NOT to criticize strikers/strikes in France or elsewhere [GO BERNIE!!], but rather to say that I have witnessed some pretty impressive winter storms in Paris, which makes me question *WordReference*'s reason!)

Comment: Les Snow Days sont quelque chose de typiquement nord américain. En France il n'y a pas de nom spécial et le rapport à la neige est tout autre qu'au Canada. Ça fait sourire un Français de lire que ce phénomène est essentiel et formateur dans la vie des enfants. Il neige parfois en France, ce qui oblige les établissements scolaires à fermer « en raison des conditions météorologiques », même pour quelques petits centimètres de neige, dans les régions où les services en charge des routes ne sont pas équipés pour déblayer, ce qui est fréquent en dehors des régions de montagne.

Comment: Dans la plus pure tradition des traductions littérales j'aurais proposé "jour de neige". En tout cas pour moi c'est aussi naturel de faire du shopping lors d'un jour de neige que de magasiner lors d'un snow day..

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jour_blanc_(film)

Comment: @PapaPoule Schools are not supposed to close when teachers are on strike, although they sometimes do, but very rarely, because non striking staff are compelled to look after the students (not only their own). If necessary SMA (service minimum d’accueil) is organized by the town services where primary schools are concerned and Heads where secondary schools are concerned. Although rarely put into action, teachers could be compelled by law to come to the school and look after the students. I bet hardly any French person would understand what *jour blanc* could refer to.

Comment: Au Québec il y a les journées tempêtes: ce sont des journées qui sont normalement congées pour les élèves (journée pédagogiques), mais qui seront travaillées au cas où l'école a du fermer pour cause de tempête. Elles sont logiquement placées en fin d'année scolaire. Mais je n'ai pas entendu l'expression Journée tempête pour signifier Snow Day.

Comment: @PapaPoule … [GO BERNIE!!] ça donne quoi pour les franchouillards ?

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL  J'avais pas assez de place pour mettre "FEEL THE BERN!".... Soit "GO BERNIE!" ou "FEEL THE BERN!", ca veut dire que je vais faire ce que je peux pour que [Senator Bernie Sanders](https://berniesanders.com/) soit le prochain president des etats-unis. Vu qu'il est, comme moi, tres liberal/progressive/pro-labour, meme socialist, j'avais ajoutE ca pour essayer a faire voir que je ne voulais rien dire contre les greves dont je parlais dans mon commentaire. Voila tout.

Comment: @None "Ça fait sourire un Français de lire que ce phénomène est essentiel et formateur dans la vie des enfants" — an update for you from covid times: when our school switched to remote learning from home, one of the questions raised was: "How are we supposed to have snow days when weather can't stop you from getting to school? What should we do instead?!" It was only half tongue-in-cheek :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il y a plusieurs acceptions pour le terme [*snow day*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snow_day), on parle ici de « a day when a school or other workplace is closed due to weather, especially snow. » [un jour où une école ou autre lieu de travail est fermé vu les conditions météo., en particulier la neige ; ma traduction] (Wiktionnaire), tel qu'on l'évoque dans la question.

Je pense qu'on peut parler de [*journée de tempête*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=SNOW%20DAY&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) ; Termium a recensé ça dernièrement (2019) :

> *Journée de tempête* et fermeture d’école. ([source](https://web.csdn.qc.ca/content/fermeture-pour-tempetes-ou-force-majeure))
>  L’ensemble des
>   commissions scolaires ont fermé boutique pendant cette *journée de
>   tempête*. ([source](https://www.quebechebdo.com/local/quebec-hebdo-local/actualites-quebec-hebdo-local/137289/la-pire-tempete-de-l-hiver-n-a-laisse-personne-indifferent/) )

Termium a aussi recensé « jour de neige » et « journées de neige » à l'université [McGill](https://www.mcgill.ca/isa/fr/guide/politiques#neige). Je suis davantage habitué à la référence à la *tempête*, parce que de la neige il y en a tout le temps comme on le sait et ça n'entraîne pas systématiquement le fermeture d'institutions etc.

En fait un truc comme [*classe de neige*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=CLASSE%20NEIGE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) (voir aussi [ici](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17561161) et [*classe-nature*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=CLASSE-NATURE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)) évoque l'activité physique en plein air et non le fait de rester à l'intérieur.

Comment: En France, les *classes **de** neige* envoient les enfants à la montagne.

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL Bien vu, en fait je mélange la morphologie de [classe-nature](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=CLASSE-NATURE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) ; c'est _classe de neige_ en effet, mais pour une raison je semble habitué à _classe-neige_, qu'on ne trouve pas. J'ai corrigé.

Comment: Que dis-tu sur ce "jour blanc" du film que Papa Poule a mentionné dans son commentaire ?

Comment: Je remarque qu'on a choisi _jour de neige_ au Québec pour le même film ; il y souvent des nuances qui témoignent d'approches différentes dans le doublage (des titres) de film. Je trouve _tempête_ plus évocateur et usuel. Mais je suis certain que dans ma vie j'ai dit, quand on n'attend pas de neige et qu'on se réveille le matin et qu'il y a en plein « tout est blanc dehors », mais ce n'est pas le _jour_ qui devient ainsi dans ma conception des choses. Par ailleurs j'associe aussi blanc à _blanc (trou) de mémoire_, par influence de _blank_. Le contexte aide mais _jour blanc_ peut évoquer...

Comment: ...dans mon esprit des trucs moins agréables de manière très contemporaine, comme le suprémacisme blanc. Tandis que tempête est clair, « Perturbation atmosphérique importante sur terre ou sur mer, caractérisée essentiellement par un vent violent (souvent accompagné de précipitations) et, en mer ou sur un lac, par de fortes vagues. » (TLFi). C'est le vent et la précipitations qui causent les fermeture, pas la neige en soi, et donc la je trouve la référence métonymique ou aux attributs de la neige inutile et plutôt forcée (je le conçois davantage comme un _(snow)storm day_). Mais on est libre.

Answer (score 3):

Dans le film Snoopy et les Peanuts (VF) s'emploie

> alerte neige

Les écoliers comprennent immédiatement qu'il n'y a pas d'école ce jour.

Comment: Dans les sous-titres de la zone B (Europe) peut-être mais dans la zone A (Amérique du nord) on trouve _congé pour tempête_ en provenance du Blu-Ray, je n'ai pas vu le film et je ne peux comparer l'audio. On peut comparer les sous-titres [ici](https://subscene.com/subtitles/peanuts).